# Using R to fit y ~ exp(-x^a)

Tags: r, nls

I just started using nls
I tried to fit

```
y ~  exp(-x^a) :
m<- nls(y ~  exp(-x^a),start=list(a=0))
```

It seemes to work fine :)

My problem is that I want to get out "a" in order to write the value to a file.

I can see the the value is 3.612 but how to get hold of the value?

```
m
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ exp(-x^a)
   data: parent.frame()
    a 
3.612 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.06132

Number of iterations to convergence: 9 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.654e-06
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of `a` by doing

```
coef(m)[["a"]]
```

Example (model from `help(nls)`):

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 2*x + 3                            
yeps <- y + rnorm(length(y), sd = 0.01)
(m <- nls(yeps ~ a + b*x, start = list(a = 0.12345, b = 0.54321)))
# Nonlinear regression model
# model: yeps ~ a + b * x
# data: parent.frame()
# a b 
# 3 2 
# residual sum-of-squares: 0.000834
#
# Number of iterations to convergence: 2 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.23e-09
coef(m)[["a"]]
# [1] 3.0052
```

Comment: Great - so easy :)
Thanks